# Are any quantities conserved quantities in an expanding universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, conservation-laws, space-expansion

Do we know of any quantities that are conserved on the global scale of the universe? Is there an associated continuous symmetry?

I.e. momentum and energy are not globally conserved as the expansion of the universe breaks spacetime translation symmetry.